# UTF-8 error everytime Org-gcal sync entries

Tags: org-mode, utf-8

I continue to get bogged down with this error every time I sync from gcal, I have this ut8 flag set in my config as well, any direction would be helpful.

```
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Could you please describe what you're trying to do? Not clear to me.

Comment: Sorry had a wrong title. basically, everytime I sync my google cal with org-gcal it throws this warning / error. My calender entries have special characters `å `I was under the impression that was causing it.

Comment: I created an issue in the project, have the same problem since after July.
https://github.com/kidd/org-gcal.el/issues/41.

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading **request** package to the latest version this is working for me. See this https://github.com/kidd/org-gcal.el/issues/41